# How to change the Hover event to Click event in media query 768 (Navbar)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

On my navigation there's a sub page and I'm using this code Option 1 and Option 2 are both working, and it's my choice of which one of them I'm going to use but the problem is that in mobile device view the sub pages still showing when hovering and it is bad idea for mobile, I want to achieve is that when it comes to mobile devices example size 768 the navbar is clickable and shows the subpages instead of hovering the navbar and shows the subpages.

Option 1:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Option 2:

```
jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).show();
  jQuery(this).addClass('open');
}, function() {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).hide();
  jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

My website is built in bootstrap 3, wordpress and for my navigation I'm using [navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

Hope you can help me with my in mobile devices navbar problem. Thanks

**I found the solution to my problem** 
In desktop view the Sub Pages would show when you hover the Parent Nav and In mobile devices view, the Sub Pages will only show when you click the Parent Nav.

**credit to user1079877**

```
$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function(){
    if(!$('.navbar-toggle').is(':visible')) { // disable for mobile view
        if(!$(this).hasClass('open')) { // Keeps it open when hover it again
           $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use option 1 with media query. I believe most of the touch devices' browsers will not do anything for hover.

Comment: I tried it to convert the display:block into display:none in 768 and when I click the parent nav the subpage won't show.

Answer (score 0):

You need check the width of the window and than put it in an IF condition and check if it is less than 768 than click or else do hover. See below example,

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    var width = $(window).width();

    if( width < 768 ) {

        // click event here

    } else {

        // hover event here

    }

});
```

Try this, hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi @Airish how can I convert my jquery code (Option 2) the hover event to click event in jquery? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Or, simply you can bind for both events.

Comment: I tried to change the .hover to .click in my code: jQuery('ul.nav li.dropdown'). **click** (function() but no luck

Comment: @MelvinRey can you post your HTML code also for the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32546/)** Is this you want to achieve?

```
function toggleNavbarMethod() {
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
      $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click').blur();
    });
  } else {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').off('mouseover').off('mouseout');
  }
}
toggleNavbarMethod();
$(window).resize(toggleNavbarMethod);
```

Comment: The hover event in desktop does not work properly after several resizing the view. Anyway, thanks for the help. I found the answer to my problem in navwalker. please see my updated post for future reference.